# posix_memalign memory allocation and memory free

Tags: c++

In the following codes, do I need to free allocated_memory2 and allocated_memory3? Do you think this code is free of memory leaks?

```
class data {
public:
    data();
    ~data();
    unsigned char *allocated_memory1;  
    unsigned char *allocated_memory2;  
    unsigned char *allocated_memory3;  
};

data::data() {
    posix_memalign((void **) &allocated_memory1, 16, 1040);
    memset(allocated_memory1, 0, 1040);

    allocated_memory2 = allocated_memory1 + 4;
    allocated_memory3 = allocated_memory1 + 16;
}

data::~data() {
    free(allocated_memory3);
    free(allocated_memory2);
    free(allocated_memory1);
}
```

Comment: One call to free for every call to an allocation function.  Only free pointers returned by memory allocators. Do not free the 2 and 3 pointers.

Comment: It's not free of crashes when feeding free() with pointers that were not allocated with new().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Free'ing only `allocated_memory1` (allocated by `posix_memalign` call) is sufficient/correct. `allocated_memory2` and `allocated_memory3` are simply pointers to different parts of the same block of memory. So free'ing them is incorrect.

You may avoid exposing the `allocated_memory1` pointer directly - in case it get changed, you might not be able to free it. You could use:

```
class data {

private:
    unsigned char *allocated_block;

public:
    data();
    ~data();
    unsigned char *allocated_memory1;  
    unsigned char *allocated_memory2;  
    unsigned char *allocated_memory3;  
};

data::data() {
    posix_memalign((void **) &allocated_block, 16, 1040);
    memset(allocated_block, 0, 1040);

    allocated_memory1 = allocated_block + 4;
    allocated_memory2 = allocated_block + 4;
    allocated_memory3 = allocated_block + 16;
}

data::~data() {
    free(allocated_block);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating a single block of memory. The other two pointers simply point into that memory. Therefore, you don't have a memory leak, but you do have invalid `free`s which means undefined behavior (likely crashing the program or worse).

Also, you should check the return value of `posix_memalign` for errors.

Ideally, you would use a [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) to keep track of the allocated memory, which means you won't need to write a destructor. Use a custom deleter to ensure it is released with `free`.

Finally, it is best if you explicitly disable copy/move for this class unless you handle it.

Comment: I would add that the unique_ptr needs a custom deleter in OP case. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @CuriouslyRecurringThoughts You aren't! It *may* work without it, since POSIX says the memory can be deleted with `free` and some implementations may just call that from `delete`, but it is UB.